# dropdownlist items find by partial value

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

To find an item (and select it) in a dropdownlist using a value we simply do

```
dropdownlist1.Items.FindByValue("myValue").Selected = true;
```

How can I find an item using partial value? Say I have 3 elements and they have values "myValue one", "myvalue two", "myValue three" respectively.  I want to do something like

```
dropdownlist1.Items.FindByValue("three").Selected = true;
```

and have it select the last item.

Comment: Where do I find dropdownlist? or what type of collection is the "Items"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can iterate from the end of the list and check if value contains the item (this will select the last item which contains value "myValueSearched").

```
 for (int i = DropDownList1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Value.Contains("myValueSearched"))
            {
                DropDownList1.Items[i].Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Or you can use linq as always:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                   .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("three"))
                   .LastOrDefault().Selected = true;
```

Comment: Oooh I love linq. Thank you.

Comment: i have many such drop downs in my page say 20,and each drop down has to loop through 3000 records to find the matched partial value with dataset column.so by this approach i guess it will hit the performance alot. please suggest any best way if u have idea

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the items in your list, and when you find the first one whose items's string contains the pattern, you can set its Selected property to true.

```
bool found = false;
int i = 0;
while (!found && i<dropdownlist1.Items.Count)
{
       if (dropdownlist1.Items.ToString().Contains("three"))
              found = true;
       else
              i++;
}
if(found)
     dropdownlist1.Items[i].Selected = true;
```

Or you could write a method (or extension method) that does this for you

```
public bool SelectByPartOfTheValue(typeOfTheItem[] items, string part)
{
    bool found = false;
    bool retVal = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (!found && i<dropdownlist1.Items.Count)
    {
           if (items.ToString().Contains("three"))
                  found = true;
           else
                  i++;
    }
    if(found)
    {
           items[i].Selected = true;
           retVal = true;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

and call it like this

```
if(SelectByPartOfTheValue(dropdownlist1.Items, "three")
     MessageBox.Show("Succesfully selected");
else
     MessageBox.Show("There is no item that contains three");
```

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned answers are perfect, just there are not case sensitivity proof :

```
DDL.SelectedValue = DDL.Items.Cast<ListItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.ToLower().Contains(matchingItem)).Text
```