# search in combobox while typing using wildcard character % in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to use wildcard character `'%'+Text'%'`, but it doesn't work at all. The dropped down list is always showing kind of that form `Text+'%'`

Here is my code

```
    private void cboEmp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cboEmp.Text.Trim()))
            cboEmp.SelectedIndex = cboEmp.FindStringExact('%'+cboEmp.Text+'%');
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you may only be changing the index if there is nothing in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

`FindStringExact` means the entire string must match.

`FindString` will match anything that starts with the characters entered.  This is probably your better choice.

As far as being able to do a partial search, you would have to write code to traverse the items.  This might answer your need: [dropdownlist items find by partial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694227/dropdownlist-items-find-by-partial-value)